# Раздельно или слитно «не интегрированными»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

*Дети из семей мигрантов порой не ходят в школу, оказываются не интегрированными и лишенными многого, что доступно их сверстникам из коренных московских семей.*

Подскажите, "не интегрированными" — раздельно или слитно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Интегрированный](https://orthographic.academic.ru/23536/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — это страдательное причастие (от *интегрировать*).
В этом предложении оно не имеет зависимых слов и, предполагаю, является субстантивированным (то есть перешедшим в разряд существительных). В этом случае с "не" оно пишется слитно.

**Дети из семей мигрантов порой не ходят в школу, оказываются** (какими? кем?) **неинтегрированными...**

*Но с другой стороны, интегрированным или **неинтегрированным** может быть только конкретный человек, носитель сознания* ([из интервью](http://www.moles.ee/01/Apr/09/5-1.html) с В. Киреевым).

[НЕ с причастиями](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-017.htm)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на Киреева. Очень интересно и полезно.

Comment: И Вам спасибо за добрые слова — приятно ощущать себя полезной. В Эстонии интеграция русскоязычного населения — это, к сожалению, больной (и с кавычками, и без кавычек) вопрос!